# import statement for Jackson JavaTimeModule not recognized

Tags: java, jackson-modules

I need to use the Jackson module JavaTimeModule.
I added the jar to my gradle build:

```
 compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.4")
```

I successfully build the project and the jar is downloaded to my lib folder. 
I refresh the project and select Gradle Refresh Project in Eclipse.
Yet the import statement is not recognized:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake...I had to add the jar to my build path.
So if any other newbies, go to Java Build Path, Libraries tab.
Add External Jar (navigate to the folder that has jackson-datatype-jsr310 and add.

Fixed it.